# MVC2 - IIS7, Virtual Directory - Url.Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, virtual-directory

I have MVC2 applications that runs well on the root of website, however when I publish it to a Virtual Directory, none of the images or css worked.  I used Url.Content, and all worked except for video files using Javascript and JW Player.
I am building my dynamic buttons using:

> onClick = string.Format("videoplayer('../video/{0}')", VideoName);

Now I need to use Url.Content, tried several ways but failed, I would appreciate your input.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could separate your markup and javascript. For example you could use HTML5 `data-*` attributes and jQuery:

```
<div class="player" data-url="<%= Url.Content("~/video") %>/foo.avi">
    Play foo
</div>

<div class="player" data-url="<%= Url.Content("~/video") %>/bar.avi">
    Play bar
</div>
```

and then in a separate javascript file you could subscribe to the `.click` event:

```
$(function() {
    $('.player').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).data('url');
        videoplayer(url);      
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, your solution works well; however I would like to place '<%= Url.Content("~/video/" + VideoName) %>' in my existing fuction(videoname){ var videotoplay = '<%= Url.Content("~" + videoname) %>';
I get the videoname from my button as /video/test.mp4.  I am getting error The name 'videoname' does not exist in the current context.  Thanks

Comment: @user373721, ah, so `videoname` is a javascript variable? You should have explained that in your question. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Darin is correct but you also need to learn some debugging skills. Use Fiddler/F12 tools and even view source to figure out the requested URL and why it's not working.